# Python mysql are prepared statements enough or do I need escape_string()?

Tags: python, mysql

So is this :

```
cursor.execute("Insert INTO visit (pid, date, diagnosisid) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)",
(pid, date, diagnosisid))
```

enough or do I need :

```
cursor.execute("Insert INTO visit (pid, date, diagnosisid) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)",
(escape_string(pid), escape_string(date), escape_string(diagnosisid)))
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is enough; the second one would double your efforts, replacing e.g. `"` with `\"`. You can test it yourself with

```
>>> c.execute("SELECT %s, %s", ('"', MySQLdb.escape_string('"')))
1L
>>> c.fetchall()
((u'"', u'\\"'),)
```

So you see that the 2nd version would produce an unneeded `\` before the `"`. So the first one is ok.

Answer (score 3):

The first code example is already safe against SQL injection. The second example will cause additional quotes in your database, which is most likely **not** what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As long as its not a formatted string and they truly are prepared statements, you shouldn't have to worry.

It might cause more problems than its worth to escape it twice.

Comment: Escaping twice **always** leads to problems.